# Picking a data structure in STL that has fastest possible insertion and lookups

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I am looking for a data structure that stores integers in the STL.

The main operations I have to support are insertion and removal, finding the top 20 elements, and finding the k-th largest element for any k.

I know that with a set, I can implement insert and remove in log N time, top 20 in O(1) time, and top k in O(k) time.

Is there any way to pick a data structure which might have a better ability to find the top k entry? For instance, picking k = N/2---the median---it will require O(N) time using a set, but ideally we can have something better.

Comment: *I am looking for a data structure* Do you mean a container?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: You could start by exploring this : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container. I think knowing what C++ has to offer is more useful to you than us pointing out a potential match. Only you know your requirements best. Also have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm there might be a partial sort algorithm that can be of use

Comment: Theoretically `std::set` can support finding the `k`-th element in logarithm time, but this is not exposed by the API. You'd have better luck using a custom data structure.

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps: [Data structure (in STL or Boost) for retrieving kth smallest/largest item in a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59041681/9171697). This supports only a fixed value for K though.

Comment: How many integers?

Comment: It is a stream so it could be arbitrary.

Comment: @DrewBrady - Do we have a ballpark figure? Can it be less than 10? More than a billion? If there had been a "best container for everything", we would only have had that one.

Comment: Less than a billion

Answer (score 0):

hash table does insertion, deletion and searching in o(1) time. so this

Comment: Except that O(1) doesn't mean "fast" but "always takes about the same time".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/hash-map-class

Looks like the hash_map is not available anymore and as per MSDN the suggestion is to use unordered_map. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/unordered-map-class